# Getting Error Installing Magento in WAMP Server

Tags: php, mysql, magento

There has been an error processing your request

```
Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\sql\salesrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'period',
```

query was:

```
  CREATE TABLE `coupon_aggregated_updated` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Id' ,
  `period` date NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'Period' ,
  `store_id` smallint UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Store Id' ,
  `order_status` varchar(50) NULL COMMENT 'Order Status' ,
  `coupon_code` varchar(50) NULL COMMENT 'Coupon Code' ,
  `coupon_uses` int NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Coupon Uses' ,
  `subtotal_amount` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Subtotal Amount' ,
  `discount_amount` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Amount' ,
  `total_amount` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Total Amount' ,
  `subtotal_amount_actual` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Subtotal Amount Actual'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CURDATE()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp) or '0000-00-00'. Look in [wiki](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html)

```
...

`period` date NOT NULL default CURDATE() COMMENT 'Period' ,

...
```